# AIP backup - using Docker

Tags: database, docker, backup, dspace

I am using the cloned dspace 6-x branch and installed it via docker. Can someone help me with the backup of my local database (Communities, collections, items)to a remote database?
According to the documentation we need to use the command:

dspace packager -s -t AIP -e eperson -p  parent-handle file-path

But it returns an error: dspace is not a command

Anyone could help me transfer my local database to my remote repo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Moving publications to a new repository will be a more substantial undertaking!

But your recent problem seems just that you are either not on the right container or in the right directory for executing the `dspace` command. Thus it is "not found". Make sure to execute `dspace` on the dspace container and specify the right/complete path. The dspace command is located in
`/path/to/your/dspace-deployement-directory/bin`.